# Stored procedure to decrease reservation hours in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am have a library seat reservation system and i am writing a stored procedure to decrease the number of hours for students according to certain rules and it should repeat every day at 7 am. the number of hours a student can reserve depends on the reputation he or she has. but in addition to the reputation the hours reserved before for the day should be taken into account and decreased from the number of hours a student can reserve on this day. example: a student with reputation=5 can reserve 8 hours a day but if this student reserved 2 hours for the day the number of hours left will be 8-2=6. The stored procedure works as supposed to work when the student doesn't have any reservation but when a student has a reservation on that day it sets the number of hours to 0 which is not supposed to happen. I am not able to point out the problem and there is no debugger to use.

this is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateHours`()
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE v_email1 varchar(255) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_reputation int(11) default 0;

DECLARE v_email2 varchar(255) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_stime varchar(255) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_etime varchar(255) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_priority tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_hours double DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE d_stime datetime;
DECLARE d_etime datetime;
DECLARE checkDate bool DEFAULT false;

DECLARE student cursor for select Email, reputation from students;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished1 = 1;

OPEN student;

get_email1: LOOP

set v_hours=0;
FETCH student INTO v_email1, v_reputation;
IF v_finished1 = 1 THEN 
LEAVE get_email1;
END IF;
block2:
begin

DECLARE v_finished2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE reservation cursor for select student_email, stime, etime, priority from reservations where str_to_date(stime,'%H:%i:%s %d/%m/%Y') between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval 1 DAY);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished2 = 1;

OPEN reservation;
get_reservation: LOOP
FETCH reservation INTO v_email2, v_stime, v_etime, v_priority;
IF v_finished2 = 1 THEN 
LEAVE get_reservation;
END IF;

set d_stime = date_format(str_to_date(v_stime,'%H:%i:%s %d/%m/%Y'),'%H:%i:%s %d/%m/%Y');
set d_etime = date_format(str_to_date(v_etime,'%H:%i:%s %d/%m/%Y'),'%H:%i:%s %d/%m/%Y');
if (v_email2 = v_email1 and v_priority = 0) then
set v_hours = v_hours + TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, d_stime, d_etime);
end if;
END LOOP get_reservation; 
CLOSE reservation; 
end block2;
If (v_reputation= 5) then
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = (8-v_hours) where Email = v_email1;

elseif (v_reputation= 4) then
 if 6>=v_hours then
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = (6-v_hours) where Email = v_email1;
 else
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = 0 where Email = v_email1;
  end if;
elseif (v_reputation= 3) then
 if 4>=v_hours then
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = (4-v_hours) where Email = v_email1;
 else
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = 0 where Email = v_email1;
  end if;   
elseif (v_reputation= 2) then
 if 2>=v_hours then
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = (2-v_hours) where Email = v_email1;
 else
  update students set ReservationHrsLeft = 0 where Email = v_email1;
  end if;
elseif v_reputation= 1 then
update students set ReservationHrsLeft = 1 where Email = v_email1;
END if;
END LOOP get_email1;

CLOSE student;
END
```

Comment: Stored procedures are quite hard to debug and test because of lack of tools. But such MySQL debuggers actually exist: dbForge, for instance. Also, I would recommend you to split you procedure into several smaller ones. Use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions to find maxima and minima of two values.

Comment: I did as you told me and it helped a lot so thank you! the problem was in the d_stime and d_etime i shouldn't have use the date_format function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the d_stime and d_etime. i shouldn't have used the date_format function.